# CODEIGNITOR 4 Not Saving Into mysql DB

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-4

I am trying to save data into mysql db, the app is not saving the data and there and no error showing either.

I have my models, views and controllers in Thirdparty\Auth.

I have other pages working well in same directory but one page (settings) just wont save input into db.

My Model code:

```
<?php namespace Auth\Models;

use CodeIgniter\Model;

class SettingsModel extends Model
{
    protected $table      = 'appsettings';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';

    protected $returnType = 'array';
    protected $useSoftDeletes = false;

    // this happens first, model removes all other fields from input data
    protected $allowedFields = [
        'appname', 'frame_ver', 'app_ver'
    ];

    protected $useTimestamps = true;
    protected $createdField  = 'created_at';
    protected $updatedField  = 'updated_at';
    protected $dateFormat    = 'int';

    protected $validationRules = [];

    // we need different rules for registration, account update, etc
    protected $dynamicRules = [
        'registration' => [
            'appname'               => 'required',
            'frame_ver'             => 'required',
            'app_ver'               => 'required'
        ]
    ];

    protected $validationMessages = [];

    protected $skipValidation = false;

    
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------

    /**
     * Retrieves validation rule
     */
    public function getRule(string $rule)
    {
        return $this->dynamicRules[$rule];
    }

    //--------------------------------------------------------------------

}
```

My Controller Code :

```
<?php
namespace Auth\Controllers;

use CodeIgniter\Controller;
use Config\Email;
use Config\Services;
use Auth\Models\SettingsModel;

class SettingsController extends Controller
{

    /**
     * Access to current session.
     *
     * @var \CodeIgniter\Session\Session
     */
    protected $session;

    /**
     * Authentication settings.
     */
    protected $config;


    //--------------------------------------------------------------------

    public function __construct()
    {
        // start session
        $this->session = Services::session();

        // load auth settings
        $this->config = config('Auth');
    }

    //--------------------------------------------------------------------

    /**
     * Settings Functions
     */
    public function Settingsfx()
    {
        if (! $this->session->isLoggedIn) {
            return redirect()->to('login');
        }

        return view($this->config->views['settings'], [
            'userData' => $this->session->userData,
            'config' => $this->config
        ]);
    }


/**
     * Attempt to register settings.
     */
    public function addsettings()
    {
        helper('text');

        // save settings, validation happens in model
        $appsettings = new SettingsModel();
        $getRule = $appsettings->getRule('registration');
        $appsettings->setValidationRules($getRule);
        $settings = [
            'appname'           => $this->request->getPost('appname'),
            'frame_ver'         => $this->request->getPost('frame_ver'),
            'app_ver'           => $this->request->getPost('app_ver')
        ];

        if (! $appsettings->save($settings)) {
            return redirect()->back()->withInput()->with('errors', $appsettings->errors());
        }

    }
}
```

Where am i mixing things? I have been trying for two days now. Any insights will be hightly appreciated.

Comment: Can you vardump settings and see if it showing up ? Also if it then try to include all the fields in the allowed fields parameter and see if it works.

Comment: how to vardump settings?

Comment: var_dump($settings); before if (! $appsettings->save($settings)) line.

Comment: Thank you, i added var_dump($settings); as directed but it didnt save to db, didnt work. Any other suggestion?

Comment: Do you see any data printed on your screen ? var_dump is to show the data on the screen. One case it maybe that data is not getting stored in $settings, hence it might throw the error.

Comment: Nothing is printed and nothing is saving. Another form has today also stopped saving part of the inputs. I dont know whats happening. No errors showing.

Comment: After a lot of research, i managed to solve the issue.